# Kivy TextInput background problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I don't like the default gradient background for the unfocused `TextInput` so I edited the default texture in Paint. But it doesn't seem to recognize it. It's in a separate file and looks like this:
[image]

The texture I get is just plain white. Do I need a specific file with the texture or to move the texture to the place where it is in the default texture?
This is a test code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class App1(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout()
        tx1 = TextInput()
        tx = TextInput(background_normal = "E:\textinput_unfocused.png")
        b.add_widget(tx1)
        b.add_widget(tx)
        return b

App1().run()
```

Oh, by the way. The source code is located in the E: disk, as well as the `textinput_unfocused.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the path for Your background should be specified relative to the app file. So if they are both in the same directory just put:

```
tx = TextInput(background_normal = "textinput_unfocused.png")
```